# Model of a chain map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

1. Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring with multiplication $\mu: R\otimes R \rightarrow R$.

- Given topological spaces $X,Y$ and open subsets $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$, pick a chain homotopy equivalence $$EZ\colon S_{\ast}(X\times Y,X\times B \cup A \times Y;R)\rightarrow S_{\ast}(X,A;R)\otimes S_{\ast}(Y,B;R).$$
- For $\alpha \in S^p(X,A;R)$ and $\beta \in S^q(Y,B;R)$, define the *cohomology cross product* as $$\alpha \times \beta:=\mu\circ(\alpha\otimes \beta)\circ EZ_{p+q}.$$
- Define the cup product next. Consider the *Alexander-Whitney diagonal map*
  $AW(X)\colon S_\ast(X)\rightarrow S_\ast(X)\otimes S_\ast(X).$ It is defined on a chain $c\in S_n(X)$ as
  $AW(X)_n(c):=\sum_{p+q=n}F^p(c)\otimes R^q(c)$, where $F^p(c)=c\circ \iota$ and $R^q(c)=c\circ \tilde{\iota}$ for the inclusions $\iota\colon \Delta^p\rightarrow \Delta^n, (t_0,\ldots, t_p)\mapsto (t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_p,0,\ldots,0)$ and $\tilde{\iota}\colon \Delta^q\rightarrow \Delta^n, (t_0,\ldots, t_q)\mapsto (0,\ldots,0,t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_q)$.
- The *cup product* $\cup \colon S^p(X)\otimes S^q(X)\rightarrow S^{p+q}(X)$ is defined as $\alpha\otimes \beta \mapsto \mu \circ (\alpha \otimes \beta) \circ \pi_{p,q} \circ AW(X)_{p+q}$, where $\pi_{p,q}\colon \oplus_{k+l=p+q}S_k(X)\otimes S_l(X)\rightarrow S_{p}(X)\otimes S_q(X)$ is the projection map.
- Consider the diagonal map $\Delta:X \rightarrow X\times X.$

2. Let $\alpha \in H^p(X)$ and $\beta \in H^q(X)$. I am looking at a proof of

$$\alpha \cup \beta = \Delta^{\ast}(\mu\circ(\alpha\otimes \beta)\circ EZ).$$
It reads

> This follows immediately if we recall that the Alexander-Whitney diagonal map $AW$ **is a model for the chain map $EZ\circ \Delta_{\ast}$.**

- **What is a model in this context, i.e. what does the quoted sentence in bold mean?**
- **Why is the Alexander-Whitney diagonal map $AW$ a model for the chain map $EZ\circ \Delta_{\ast}$?**